IDA Remote Debugging and automatically interaction with the process
I am learning IDA and currently working with the debugger. In particular, I want to automate the interaction with my remote binary (from Windows Subsystem Linux - Ubuntu 22.04 instance), like what I can did with pwntools. These interactions cover readline, sendline, etc. that can automate my interaction with the binary, and sometimes sending non-ASCII characters. Are there anyways that I can work on this? At current time, I already setup the remote debugging with Remote Linux debugger from IDA.
Thanks!

I have figured out a temporary way. Basically, I run the binary linux_server64/linux_server from IDA, inside my pwntools script. Probably there is no way to do this automation directly from IDA...
